# The connotation difference between using "the" and the plural form of a word

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural

Are both sentences below correct when I intend to talk about cotton swabs in general, not a particular one? If so, do they have different connotations?

> I am going to introduce a new use of the cotton swab.

> I am going to introduce a new use of cotton swabs.

Comment: Similarly "the man in the street" isn't a particular man or street, but generic.

Comment: Yes, the mean exactly the same thing, although the first might have slightly more dramatic appeal - as in TV advertising..